# ASP.NET - Invalid character in the given encoding .resx

Tags: asp.net, xml, localization, character-encoding

I am adding a number of languages to a client's website using the `App_LocalResource` folder containing `.resx` files.

The client's test application is hosted on a server with no outside Internet access so I have to [remote desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) to the site and manually copy any changes made via [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29)..

So far, I have manually created an `App_LocalResource` folder, created the `.resx` files and copied the source of each file via Notepad.

I am now getting a parser error:

> Parser Error Message: Invalid character in the given encoding.

```
Line 137:  </data>
Line 138:  <data name="DEATHINSERVICENOMINATIONS" xml:space="preserve">
Line 139:    <value>Mort à candidatures Prestation de service</value>
Line 140:  </data>
Line 141:  <data name="EDITPERSONALDATA" xml:space="preserve">
```

Would this possibly have something to do with me manually copying these files across using Notepad or is there another reason for it?

I have added this to the `web.config` file:

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8"
    requestEncoding="utf-8"
    responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add an `encoding` property in your resx file, at first line, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: That was it. My encoding was set to utf-8 by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but your RESX file probably needs to identify itself to the XML parser as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). One way to be sure what's causing it is to use binary search (remove half the file at a time recursively) until you find the part that's causing the problem. Then, if you need, you can [use CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) to escape any characters the parser doesn't like.